# NSLog detect updating current location in MKPolygon

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, cllocationmanager, mkpolygon

noob here. I've read up on how to detect a point in a MKPolygon but I'm having difficulties implementing it -- it might just have to do with the part in the code at which I'm checking the user location… I'm not even sure if it's consistently checking. Anyway, here's the relevant code:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
  didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
self.current = [locations lastObject];
NSLog(@"lat%f - lon%f", self.current.coordinate.latitude, self.current.coordinate.longitude);
NSLog(@"%@", self.mapCIIP); }
```

and later

```
-(MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay{
if([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolygon class]]){
    MKPolygonRenderer *view = [[MKPolygonRenderer alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
    view.lineWidth=1;
    view.strokeColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    view.fillColor=[[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];


    return view;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D mapCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.current.coordinate.latitude, self.current.coordinate.longitude);

    MKMapPoint mapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(mapCoordinate);
    if (CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(mapCoordinate)) {
        NSLog(@"Coordinate valid");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Coordinate invalid");
    }

    CGPoint polygonViewPoint = [view pointForMapPoint:mapPoint];


    if ( CGPathContainsPoint(view.path, NULL, polygonViewPoint, NO) ) {
        self.mapCIIP = @"TRUE";
    }
    else {
        self.mapCIIP = @"false";
    };


}
return nil; }
```

I simulated different locations in Xcode with it running on my iPhone, and while the lat/long update, it's not giving me what I want for the true/false in the polygon I drew. At one point it was showing up as all true but now it's all (null) in NSLog. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Part way through your function it returns the `view`, so the code setting the `mapCIIP` can't be reached.

Comment: I moved the `return view` to the very end of `if([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolygon class]])`, but I'm still not showing a switch when I change the current location to inside or outside the polygon -- it's all `false`

Comment: I can't see any record of what `MKPolygonRenderer` is or what its `pointForMapPoint` function should do, though I can guess. Can you link to some documentation for it.